# Shrinkwrap Effect in Geo Nodes?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

[image]

I am wondering if the following is possible. I am hoping to 'shrinkwrap' the Hexagon pattern to the surface of the model. Difficulty I have is it needs to be done in a non destructive way. If you take a look at the [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/eq0iouvbvpvgab1jimp3z/Hex-Test.blend?rlkey=7jjbdsb0yclrbbpn5gkiyukz5&dl=0) you will see that I have a combination of geo nodes and modifiers.

The hexagon pattern needs to apply after the extrusion (in geo nodes) and ideally it needs to be booleaned out of the final shape to form a grip texture.

In the blend file you will see that the current grip texture I have is using instances and works well as is. There's got to be a way to do this surely?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

This is the set of nodes, that I have used:

[image]

The trick here is to boolean before deformation. So look there is the GN nodes in the list.

This requires to add additional nodes to transfer vertex group that's required for deformations

[image]

Comment: The only difficulty with that is the topside edge of the outer paddle is resulting in  'twisting' geometry. I had already achieved this with modifiers but came across the same problem. I have shown the example here vs the original blend file.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6i9byze0d0mkim89tx0xh/Angles.jpg?rlkey=o2pa8ve3pjuna0j0tqnevh99s&dl=0